Xcode 15 Code Signing Verification always Succeeded
I encountered a scenario where I replaced an XCFramework in my sample project with a version signed by a different self-signed certificate in Xcode. Initially, the XCFramework was signed with a self-signed certificate named "ANAnimationSigningCert". Later, I created a new self-signed certificate named "ANAnimationSigningCert2" and code signed a new version of the XCFramework with this certificate.
According to a WWDC23 video session https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10061, Xcode should detect the change in code signing identity for the XCFramework and prompt the developer to approve or reject the new code signing identity upon building the project. However, in my case, Xcode did not automatically detect the change and did not prompt for approval or rejection. Instead, the project built successfully without any indication of the code signing change.
I'm curious why Xcode behaves this way and why it does not follow the expected behavior of prompting for approval or rejection of the updated code signing identity.
Could someone please shed some light on this behavior and provide insights into why Xcode does not prompt for approval or rejection in such scenarios?
